# how do i take a long input after a string one

Tags: java, input

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the details given below.");
    System.out.println("Name:");name=sc.next();
    sc.next();

    System.out.println("Phone/mobile number:+91 ");phone_num=sc.nextLong();
    System.out.println("Home Address:");address=sc.next();
    sc.next();
    System.out.println("Pincode:");pincode=sc.nextLong();
    System.out.println("E-mail address:");e_mail=sc.next();
    sc.next();
```

this code snippet does not let me take the input to the pincode variable.

Comment: Read the javadocs fo the `next()` and `nexlLine()` methods carefully.  Then look at your code.  Repeat, until you have figured it out!!  This is a debugging problem ... and you need to work it out for yourself.  Otherwise you won't be able to do this thing in an exam or a job interview.

Answer (score 0):

I see three things you need to change.

- Get rid of all those extra `sc.next()` lines that don't assign the value to a variable. There's no reason why you'd want to read in an extra token at those points.
- Consider using `sc.nextLine()` instead of `sc.next()` to read in a `String`, so that if there are any spaces in the input, they become part of the `String`.
- Read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045) which explain a problem you might run into after the call to `sc.nextLong()` and how to deal with it.